# Installed Spyder 4.0 using anaconda now it fails to open

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I uninstalled my old version of spyder and installed spyder 4.0 using anaconda navigator. When I try to run spyder I get the following error message. What do I need to do to install spyder 4.0 correctly?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 215, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 167, in 
from spyder.utils.environ import WinUserEnvDialog
File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py", line 19, in 
from spyder.plugins.variableexplorer.widgets.collectionseditor import (
File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\variableexplorer\widgets\collectionseditor.py", line 29, in 
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
File "C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pympler\asizeof.py", line 1505, in 
for d in (numpy.array(range(0)), numpy.arange(0),
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

Comment: if you used pip to update to Spyder 4, now you need to reinstall Anaconda. If you didn't, your problem above indicates that you used pip to install some other packages in the past and you also have to reinstall Anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update numpy using the following command:

`conda install -f numpy`

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is **totally** wrong!! You can't mix pip and conda packages because those are incompatible and it breaks your Anaconda installation.

Comment: I edited the answer to mention conda instead of pip.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you Carlos, you are right, my bad, for some reason I thought he was using normal Python installation, sorry.